# Kafka producer - How to change a topic without down-time and preserving message ordering?

Tags: avro, messaging, kafka-producer-api

This question is about architecture and kafka topics migrating.

**Original problem**:  schema evolution without backward compatibility.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html

I am asking the community to give me an advice or share articles from which I can get inspired and maybe think of a solution to my problem. Maybe there is an architecture or streaming pattern. It is not necessary to give me a language specific solution; just give me a direction into which I can go... My question is big, it may be interesting for those who later want

- a) change message format and produce message into a new topic.
- b) stop producing message into one topic and start producing messages into another topic "instantly"; in other words once a message in `v2` was produced, no new messages are appended into `v1`.

### Problem

I am changing message format, which is not compatible with the pervious version. In order not to break existing consumers, I decided to produce message to a new topic.

### Up-caster idea

I have read about an up-caster.

https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/production-considerations/versioning-events

### Formal task

Let `v1` and `v2` be the topics. Currently, I produce messages in the format `format_v1` into the topic `v1`. I want to produce messages in the format `format_v2` into the topic `v2`. The switch should happen at some moment of time which I can choose.

In other words, at some moment of time, all instances of the producer stop sending messages into `v1`, and start sending messages into `v2`; thus the last message `m1` in `v1` is produced before the first message of `m2` in `v2`.

### Details

I got an idea, that I can produce messages to the topic `v1` have a kafka steam up-caster that is subscribed to `v1` and pushes transformed messages to `v2`. Let assume that the transformer (**in my case of course**) is able to transform message of `format_v1` into `format_v2` without errors.

As described in the link above about avro schema evolution, by the time I have added an up-caster and produce messages into `v1`, I have all my consumers of `v1` changed into `v2`.

Now, a tricky part. We have two requirements:

**1.** No production down-time.

**2.** Preserve message ordering.

It means:

1) We are not allowed to lose messages; a client may use our system at any time, so our system should produce a message at any time.

2) We are running multiple instances of the producer. At some moment of time there can  (potentially) be producers that may produce messages of format `format_v1` into the topic `v1`, and some instances that produce messages of format `format_v2` into the topic `v2`.

As we know, kafka does not guarantee message ordering for different partitions and topics.

I can solve the problem with partitions by writing message into v2 with the same partition selector as for v1. Or for now, I can imagine that we use just one partition for `v1` and one partition for `v2`.

---

### My simplifications and attempts

1) I imagined that by the moment I want to change the producer to produce messages into a new topic, I have an up-caster (kafka stream component) that is capable of transforming messages from `v1` into `v2` without error. This kafka stream component is scalable.

2) All my consumers have been already switched into `v2` topic. They constantly receive messages from `v2`. At this moment of time, my producer instances are producing messages into the topic `v1` and up-caster does its job well.

3) To simplify the problem, let's imagine that for now `format_v1` and `format_v2` do not matter, and they are the same.

4) Let's imagine we have one partition for `v1` and one partition for `v2`.

Now my problem, how to instantly switch all producers that from a given point of time; all the instances produce messages into the topic v2.

My colleague and kafka expert told me that with down-time it can be done

> If you rely on the order of the messages in the partitions, you cannot switch to the new version without down time. To make down time minimal we can do the following.
>
> Upcaster component must write the data to the same partitions and should try to make the same offsets. However it is not always possible, as offsets may have gaps, so the mapping between old offsets, and new offsets must be kept. No all the records, only the last bulk for each partition.  If upcaster crashes, just start again, producer is still not involved in v2.
>
> Start the v2 consumer. If it starts with the same consumer group as v1, nothing  should be done, if it has new consumer group, update offsets in Kafka according to the new offsets.
>
> Now Producers writes to v1, upcaster converts the data, consumer consumes from v2
>
> Here comes down time. When the lag of upcaster is close to 0, shutdown v1 producer, wait until upcaster converts rest of the records, shutdown upcaster, start v2 producer, which writes to v2 topic.

I though of manual manipulation in the database (via some rest-endpoint or etc) to change a flag; producers always check the flag before they produce messages. When the flag says `v2` or `true`, the producer will start writing messages into `v2`. However, what if at moment of time  the flag is false one producers starts producing message into `v1`, then the flag has changed and another producer has sent a message into `v2` before the previous producer finished producing into `v1`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it acceptable for you to have only one producer being active?

In that case you can use your idea with a flag:

1. Shut down all producers `p2`,`p3`,...,`pn` except `p1`
2. `p1` writes to `v1` alone
3. Switch the flag to `v2`, so `p1` ends its last write to `v1` and starts writing to `v2`
4. Now nobody writes to `v1`
5. Start your other producers `p2`,`p3`,...,`pn`
6. Every producer writes now because of the active flag to `v2` and still nobody to `v1`

Comment: I agree, it is possible, thanks. I will make more research and see maybe there are other advice.

Comment: There is one drawback though. Look, I do not mean to criticize your answer, I just want everybody who reads can learn. The good point of the solution above, it is doable and not complex (can be done and it is clear how!). 

On the other side, imagine you have multiple environments: develop, staging, test, pre-prod, prod. What it means that there are jobs that need to be done: `for each environment:` `stop producers except one`, `switch feature flag`, `start producers again`. Just think, how to automate all these jobs (or reduce amount of manual work). And in this case, it will be amazing!

Comment: Yes you're right. I wouldn't recommend to do these steps manually. Automate everything you can what you plan to do multiple times to possibly save time and prevent errors. In my naive imagination such a script for automation would be very easy to implement because each step is simple.